# Проверить, содержатся ли в столбце только одинаковые значения

Tags: php, mysql

есть таблица:

```
id | user
---------
1  | 300
---------
2  | 300
---------
3  | 301
---------
4  | 300
```

Как проверить, содержатся ли в столбце `user` только одинаковые значения?

**уточнение на основании комментариев**:
если только одинаковые, нужно вернуть `ok`, если встречаются разные, вернуть `no`. для приведённой в примере таблицы следует вернуть `no` (так как не все значения одинаковы).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если я правильно понял вопрос, то вывести список уникальных значений в столбце `user` можно, например так, как в первом запросе (а потом лишь подсчитать количество возвращённых строк: если больше одной — не все значения одинаковы).

**дополнение**

если же нужно получить именно `ok` (или `no` в противном случае), то можно сделать примерно как во втором и третьем запросе (во втором запросе для иллюстрации игнорируется строка с `id=3`):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13602/12)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (id int, user int);
insert into t values (1, 300), (2,300), (3, 301), (4, 300);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select distinct user from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13602/12/0)**:

```
| user |
|------|
|  300 |
|  301 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select if(count(*)=1,'ok','no') as result from (select distinct user from t where id <> 3) as s
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13602/12/1)**:

```
| result |
|--------|
|     ok |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select if(count(*)=1,'ok','no') as result from (select distinct user from t) as s
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13602/12/2)**:

```
| result |
|--------|
|     no |
```

Comment: нужно если юзер везде один $user = 'ok'; если юзера больше 1 $user = 'no';

Comment: mysqli_num_rows к этому запросу подставить и всё

Comment: @Rufex, дополнил ответ примером, возвращающим `ok` или `no`.